# Where was this photo taken - eagle and waterfall wallpaper photo?

Tags: identify-this, photography, waterfalls

My Mac comes with this photo as a sample wallpaper. I believe the photo is called "Lone Eagle."
Where was this photo taken?  Thanks!

[image: Photo]

Comment: Probably somewhere on Earth

Comment: @Midavalo or it's a painting and not from somewhere on Earth

Comment: While the close notice says you can edit details into the question, the photo does not contain any details which can be recognized. As such only the information behind the photo can give information and this kind of question is not for that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Location: [Victoria Falls, Zimbabwe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Victoria_Falls). [Source](https://www.stevebloom.com/index.php?page=single&id=003281-SB2). [Gmaps](https://goo.gl/maps/DNR1MRKjRGorvjMS8).

[Full image credits](https://www.stevebloom.com/index.php?page=single&id=003281-SB2):

> African Fish Eagle in flight, Victoria Falls, Zimbabwe - 003281-SB1
> Haliaeetus vocifer - Steve Bloom

Another angle:

[image]

Image By Diego Delso, CC BY-SA 4.0, https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/index.php?curid=73750632

Comment: Perfect. And good find anyway.